# NFS server in Vista?

Tags: unix, windows-vista, nfs

Does Vista Ultimate features a NFS server? I have very little experience in this area, but I have a unix-based device which can mount nfs shares and I would like to serve files to it. Is this possible using just Vista or I need a third-party software?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's on in microsoft Services For Unix Applications, which should be available for Vista ultimate. Details can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sfu/archive/2007/05/01/unix-interoperability-and-windows-vista.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question hasn't been marked closed or answered, I'd like to offer some input.
Services for Unix (SFU) Applications is available from Microsoft, and appears to support all versions of MS Windows - however the installer does warn that there are compatibility issues with Vista.
My efforts to use SFU (explicitly for NFS services) have repeatedly failed, despite having meticulously followed several guides.
If there are any lingering MS Vista users attempting to achieve NFS server capability, you'll have a significantly easier time installing FreeBSD.